# Jsoup getElementsByTag

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I am creating an app for my school to make it easier to check what lesson you have. im using their site but they obiously dont have a simple API. so i need to like read the site down and get everything out in pieces. (the single tags in deep in layers of tables).
so this is what i am currently using:

```
doc.body().getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(1).getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr").get(1).getElementsByTag("td").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(0).getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr").get(0).getElementsByTag("td").get(0).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).html()
```

doc = Jsoup parsed document.
for this code it works all fine, but as soon as i i try this:

```
doc.body().getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(1).getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr").get(2).getElementsByTag("td").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(0).getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr").get(0).getElementsByTag("td").get(0).getElementsByTag("a").get(0).html()
```

it returns an error.

```
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ Stack [1]: java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ Stack [2]: com.jmtech.jordi.mwc.BackgroundWorker.update_r_n(BackgroundWorker.java:374)
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ Stack [3]: com.jmtech.jordi.mwc.BackgroundWorker.access$500(BackgroundWorker.java:54)
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ Stack [4]: com.jmtech.jordi.mwc.BackgroundWorker$UpdateRaster_Raster_Notify.run(BackgroundWorker.java:355)
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ Stack [5]: java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
03-02 11:30:14.239  15253-15280/? D/JM﹕ java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

this is the schools site: http://maaswaal.roosternet.nl/?les=3H1
i cant copy&paste HTML because Stackoverflow's question div transfers code to the site, sorry.
Thanks for your time to respond already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see any `tbody` in the HTML source - but you are trying try to access it.

Remove all `.getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0)` and try.

---

I just checked - i get what is going on!

When it is executed - 2nd Table and 3rd Row

`doc.body().getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(1).getElementsByTag("tr").get(2)`

It returns below section highlighted between **. Because there is a `tr` tag. It does not give you all the rows in the same level.

```
<table class="maintableles">
        <tr>
           <th>3H1</th>
           <th class="lesdagen">maandag</th>
           <th class="lesdagen">dinsdag</th>
           <th class="lesdagen">woensdag</th>
           <th class="lesdagen">donderdag</th>
           <th class="lesdagen">vrijdag</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th class="lesuren">
              <div class="lesurendiv">1e uur</div>
           </th>
           <td>
              <table>
                 **<tr>
                    <td><a href="?les=BRS">BRS</a></td>
                    <td><a title="rekenen">rek</a></td>
                    <td align="right"><a href="?les=V110">V110</a></td>
                 </tr>**
              </table>
           </td>
           <td>
```

---

You can use CSS selector for this which is easier compared to your approach!!.

`doc.select("body > div > table.maintableles > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > a").html()`

Comment: @JMgamerZzzTM, which text you are trying to access?

Comment: didnt work, still have the same error ive breached down the code part by part and found that the error would exactly occur here: doc.body().getElementsByTag("div").get(0).getElementsByTag("table").get(1).getElementsByTag("tbody").get(0).getElementsByTag("tr").get(2).getElementsByTag("td").get(0). where the second table is trying to be gathered

Comment: if you go to the site you see the Names (shortcuts), Room numbers and lesson shortcuts in table tabs. im trying to get them all into an array sorted by day/hour.

Comment: the sepperating by date can be done in java i just need to fix the error that it cant find the element that actually exists.

Comment: What browser are you using i cant see it with google chrome?

Comment: @JMgamerZzzTM, check now. use CSS selector